# Compare line by line between two files and get store unique data in 2nd file [linux/java]

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to make a shell script that will compare two files and append the unique lines in file 1 to file 2.

So, to be more objective:
A fine named temp.txt will be overwritten with a log-file data downloaded using a curl recursively for every 5 minutes.

```
curl -X GET https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications/app-name/instances/5y83962206n79e114d530a41-1/log-file -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'X-ANYPNT-ENV-ID: Sandbox' > temp.txt
```

Now, i also have a file named backup.txt which needs to be compared to temp.txt and add anything that is unique. The following scenarios arise

1. During the 1st run the whole temp.txt is copied to backup.txt
   [1st Run File content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV54M.png)
2. In 2nd run only the new lines if any should be added to backup.txt
   [2nd Run File content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fvr0.png)

I was able to achieve till here using the ***comm*** utility of linux

There may also be a situation where the temp.txt is entirely having new content from very first line.

3. In this scenario 3rd run, again we need to append the entire data to the backup.txt
   [3rd Run File content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64gbL.png)
4. In the 4th run we will have new lines compared to the content in 3rd run but completely different compared to the 1st and 2nd run content.
   [4th Run File content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkfpe.png)

Here is the challenge i am facing and unable to proceed further.

I have used ***awk*** as below from one of the SO links

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]' file2.txt file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

but it fails when there similar lines from 1st and 2nd runs. It omits those lines! Ex: the json in 3rd and 4th run images if repeated common lines is ignored.

> "httpStatus": 400, "errorOccurred": true"

The above fields are ignored while using awk causing loss of data.

Any help is higly appreciated! I have not had a java code yet but i am primary looking for a logic help here.

Regards

Kaushik

Comment: How on earth is this related to java??

Comment: Why not, could we not write a code in java to achieve the above use case? Moreover, i am primarily looking for a logic actually!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the copy of newly downloaded file if it has all the content of the backup + some new lines?

Comment: But if you refer to the third run scenario i explained, there may a situation where the downloaded file may be entirely different compared to the downloaded file in earlier times. That is the whole reason of looking for a logic to retain only the new lines...